# Multiple figure arrangement using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can we control where [Matplotlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) places figures on the screen?

I want to generate four figures (in four separate windows) that do not overlap.

Comment: A little more info would be helpful.  what OS?  I assume it is not sufficient to have four axes on one figure.  But why?  What makes four separate windows preferable?  Do you need the plots to be interactive/animated?

Answer (score 8):

From [IPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) you can do the following:

```
figure()
get_current_fig_manager().window.wm_geometry("400x600+20+40")
```

Or equivalently in a Python script:

```
import pylab as pl
pl.figure()
pl.get_current_fig_manager().window.wm_geometry("400x600+20+40")
pl.show()
```

Note that this assumes you're using the TkAgg backend.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks. I added the following two lines in front of your script to get it working a Mac: >>>import matplotlib; >>>matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to use the IPython interface with the Qt backend to achieve a similar result:

```
import matplotlib
import pylab as pl
f1 = pl.figure()
f_manager = pl.get_current_fig_manager()
f_manager.window.move(600, 600)
pl.show()
```

With f_manager you basically have a PyQt4 object that allows you to modify the window properties as you like.